# Messages showing FB contacts as numbers

Tags: messages, facebook

Messages showing FB contacts as numbers

[image]

Here is my settings for facebook.

[image]

Comment: It shows that you are not connected to Internet ?

Comment: Is your WiFi off on purpose, if yes it might have not completed synchronization with the FB.

Comment: @Buscar웃 no i am connected, i can browse, i can browse get mail, dropbox and everything works fine.

Comment: Using Messages 7.0.1 (3322), my Facebook contacts show properly. I have the same settings as you do for Facebook, using Jabber.

Comment: @Dave pls upvote my query, so that we can have some solution.

Comment: FWIW, my account periodically has been doing the same thing. I have to go Offline, and come back on in order to resolve back into usernames. I am guessing this must mean there is an issue with Jabber and Facebook interconnectivity, but I cannot verify that.